# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find column

Tags: sorting, gridview, user-controls

I am implementing gridview sorting which is part of a user control. Below code gives me Indexoutofrange error.

The error message is at

```
dtView.Sort = strSort;
```

Errormessage:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find column TEXT_COUNTY_ID.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

```
protected void SortGridData_Hkl(Object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView _dgd_work_onoff = (GridView)Page.FindControl("bodyuc$dgd_work_onoff");
        DataSet dstemp;
        DataView dtView;
        if (ViewState["dsfetchResults"] != null)
        {
            dstemp = (DataSet)ViewState["dsfetchResults"];
            string strSortOrder = ViewState["SortOrder"].ToString();

            if (strSortOrder == "DESC")
            {
                strSortOrder = "ASC";
                ViewState["SortOrder"] = strSortOrder;
            }
            else
            {
                strSortOrder = "DESC";
                ViewState["SortOrder"] = strSortOrder;
            }

            string strSort = e.SortExpression.ToString() + " " + strSortOrder;
            ViewState["SortString"] = strSort;

            dtView = dstemp.Tables[0].DefaultView;

            dtView.Sort = strSort;
            if (dtView.Count != 0)
            {
                if (_dgd_work_onoff != null)
                {
                    _dgd_work_onoff.DataSource = dtView;
                    _dgd_work_onoff.DataBind();
                }
            }


        }
```

'dsfetchResults' is suppose to contain the data from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. The column name was different from that of the database column.